# Accompany a passenger airside at London Stansted

Tags: air-travel, airport-security, stn

I need to find a way to accompany an elderly non-English-speaking relative to the gate at London Stansted Airport. Can I buy a ticket to get through security, walk the relative to the gate and then exit back to land side? I need to understand if this is legal, or if I would be given a fine.

Comment: Does your relative have a mobility restriction?  Or alternatively, is the ticket you contemplate purchasing more than £150?

Comment: Related question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38075/why-do-i-need-to-buy-a-ticket-to-get-into-the-secure-half-of-a-us-airport/38078

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you enter the departures area without a boarding pass at London Heathrow airport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14209/can-you-enter-the-departures-area-without-a-boarding-pass-at-london-heathrow-air)

Comment: I'm sure @GayotFow has something specific in mind, but it would probably be useful if you also told us what the destination of the flight is (UK/Ireland or beyond), and whether you have any specific restrictions in terms of entry/exit of the UK (i.e. non-EEA national on a visa...).

Comment: Destination is Norway, no passport restrictions

Comment: Buy a refundable ticket to a flight much later in the day. Make sure the airline gives refunds after check in. Noone can force you to fly. Same answer http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/14218/4188 here.

Comment: Or buy a super cheap Ryanair ticket for a later flight and just throw it away

Comment: Good answer [here](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/59724/19359)

Comment: @Joe the linked question is for Heathrow, the OP is asking about Stansted

Comment: @blackbird57 Sure, but the answer is sufficiently generic.

Answer (score 4):

Typically, airlines will give you a *'Security Pass'* (instead of a boarding pass)  that allows you to go into the security area for that reason, up to the gate door. At the check-in, ask for it, together with the person needing your help. If you want to be sure that it will work, call them and confirm the process now, but I have done that before.

Note you *will* need your ID with you, and the 'Security Pass' will be printed with your name. It looks similar to a Boarding pass, but has no flight info on it.

Here are two examples that confirm this:

http://lifehacker.com/5809860/family-going-on-a-trip-you-can-walk-them-all-the-way-to-the-boarding-gate-if-you-ask

http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/practical-travel-safety-security-issues/1211383-can-person-no-boarding-pass-get-guest-pass-go-thru-security.html (there are lot of people that recommend buying a ticket, that is not needed. Check for 'Orion' and 'noname's post)

P.S. It is free.

Comment: I once brought a non-english speaker to the gate that way; and another time i left my laptop in the plane, and realized it only in the parking lot. In each case, they gave me that kind of document, and I could get through security without a problem.

Comment: Here http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/practical-travel-safety-security-issues/1211383-can-person-no-boarding-pass-get-guest-pass-go-thru-security.html are people that did the same thing without problems (there are lot of people that recommend buying a ticket, that is not needed. Check for 'Orion' and 'noname's post)

Comment: Both of these examples are in the US, which often has quite different conventions to the rest of the world. Is there any indication that it happens elsewhere?

Comment: This is also typically specific to domestic travel.